# Eclipse set up for force.com

Tags: eclipse

I am new to eclipse and force.com. I have followed the instructions on the developer site to install eclipse and set it up for force.com. But when I create a new force.com project and provide the credentials, I get an error that they are incorrect. I have tried all the combinations for the environment.
[image: login_details]

[image: error_mess]

Comment: try changing the environment dropdown from 'others' to 'sandbox' and see if it works

Comment: Also, you can log in to your org in your browser, navigate to your user record and see the related list of login history. Verify that you can see failed login attempts in the related list. If you don't, you don't have the correct username or environment.

Comment: @VK: I tried all possible combinations.

Comment: to be frank Peter, I am following the book and web site and learning. Can you please tell me how can I navigate to the user record. I may be in the record but I don't see where I can login history. Will google as well.

Comment: found it I see this

Comment: @peter: adityaallada@india.com
2/8/2015 9:00:38 PM EST 73.18.97.205 Partner Product Invalid Password Java (Salesforce.com) Unknown Apex Plugin N/A SOAP Partner 30.0

Comment: but I have followed the instructions append password+security token into password field if logging from eclipse

Comment: @PeterKnolle: I think the email they are sending out is incorrect. I was able to login without appending the security token to the password and whola I am in

Comment: Since there is a separate field for Security Token, you don't need to ALSO append it to the password in the password field. The IDE does the appending for you when it logs in.

Comment: Do you have access to the IDE with your profile or a permission set in the org you are trying to access?

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your username.Your username should be in the form of an email address, for example: user@domain.com.

Comment: yep I had a correct user id but as I was posting it online I masked it :)